# Error initializing tooling instance in Mule Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am new to Mule and was following the official tutorial in using the Anypoint Studio. I was trying to test the connection of a database connector when I found that there was an issue with the tooling instance, in which the following message was given.

[image: Error-Test_DB_Connection]

I went to check the status of the tooling instance, and it was not started. Then I tried to restart the tooling instance, but it failed as shown below.

[image: Error-Restart_instance_failed]

Below is the corresponding error message (in Workspace/.metadata/.log). Kindly see if there are any insights, thanks.

> !ENTRY org.mule.tooling.core 4 0 2018-05-16 15:23:25.104
>  !MESSAGE
>   There was an error initializing tooling instance
>  !STACK 0
>   org.mule.tooling.runtime.controller.MuleControllerException: Timeout
>   while starting mule instance
>      at
>   org.mule.tooling.runtime.controller.MuleController.start(MuleController.java:143)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.client.startup.ToolingManager.restart(ToolingManager.java:154)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.client.ui.preferences.ToolingClientPreferencesPage$1.run(ToolingClientPreferencesPage.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>  Caused
>   by: org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Condition with
>   lambda expression in
>   org.mule.tooling.runtime.controller.MuleController was not fulfilled
>   within 90 seconds.
>    at
>   org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter.await(ConditionAwaiter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.awaitility.core.CallableCondition.await(CallableCondition.java:79)
>     at
>   org.awaitility.core.CallableCondition.await(CallableCondition.java:27)
>     at
>   org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:809)
>     at
>   org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:785)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.runtime.controller.MuleController.start(MuleController.java:127)
>     ... 3 more

[Environment information]
Platform: macOS 10.13.4
AnyPoint Studio version: 7.1.2
Mule runtime version: 4.1.1 EE
JDK version: 1.8.0_172
Port 3306 outbound connection is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using the previous version (Anypoint Studio 6.4 with Mule 3.9) and there is no issue making a DB connection. In fact there isn't even a section in "Preference" which is about "Tooling" under "Anypoint Studio". Maybe there is some issue with Anypoint Studio 7.1.

Nevertheless, falling back with the previous version should be one of the solutions.

Relevant discussion in Mulesoft Forum:
https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/94528/error-initializing-tooling-instance-in-mule-anypoi-1.html

Comment: This is not currently a good solution. Anypoint Studio 6 and Anypoint Studio 7 are not compatible. Studio 6 is only for Mule 3.x applications and Studio 7 for Mule 4.x applications, which are not compatible though similar. Mule 3 is the legacy version and only the last release (Mule 3.9) is supported at this time. Mule 4 is the current version with new releases. The general recommendation is to migrate to Mule 4, hence Studio 7 only,.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in my MacOS and resolved it by following the below steps

1. goto Window > Preferences -> Anypoint Studio -> Tooling

[Click here to see Tooling screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNtBy.png)

2. Click Check status button (can be found under Life cycle)
   if you don't see "Tooling instance is running) then try restart instance or restart your Anypoint studio.
3. if you keep experience this issue on your current project, try opening another project.

For me, the moment I tried in another project (follows all above 3 steps) , I was a able to test connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Change the build path from  JRE to JDK that will solve this issue.

This video will help you to set the build path.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5xeXawYgK0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I checked the java build path is already JDK (jdk 1.8.0_172). Would it be some other issue?

Answer (score 0):

This tooling was introduced in/from Anypoint Studio version 7.1.+ , Earlier versions do not have this feature at all. Initially I had similar issue and banged my head for several days with the same problem. 
If you are setting environment variables, Makesure to restart the machine to take effect.
I use multiple versions of Anypoint Studio, instead-of Environment variables I prefer adding the Java path in (INI) file under the Studio root directory and all versions work me with no issues. However, Mulesoft support says not to touch the INI files. ( which I ignore it )

Keep this in mind, if the path is too long in the environment variables, Studio may not pick up java path from it and tooling in studio seems to be creating issues. So make sure it is mentioned at the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Hey no above solutions worked for me.

But what I am going to share did work for me.

1. Check your MAVEN_HOME path which should be set to "C:\Program Files\Apache\maven"
2. Check your JAVA_HOME path which should be set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"
3. Check your "PATH" in system variables which should kept the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin" and at **FIRST PLACE** like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;. .. . .
4. In Anypoint studio, windows->Preference->Java->installed JRE and change path to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172".
5. Update anypoint studio from check for updates.
6. Restart the anypoint studio and it will work.

Note mentioned path could be different for you and Java path is of JDK not for JRE.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue and got it resolved.!

Two steps as following

1. Before extracting the Anypoint studio zip file I renamed the zip file to a shorter name.
2. While extracting the zip file, I extracted inside C:/ folder.

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the below SOLUTION II from Mulesoft support and it worked for me. I was able to connect using MySQL after this step.

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Anypoint-Studio-7-1-3-error-tooling-not-available-exception

SOLUTION II Editing the anypoint studio .ini, changing the line: -Dorg.mule.tooling.runtime.args=-XX:-UseBiasedLocking by appending ",-Dtools.jar=\lib\tools.jar"

Answer (score -1):

Below are the solutions:

First, You have to set manually your proxy configuration(if there is a proxy) in Anypoint Studio:

On the Anypoint Studio menu select “Window –> Preferences -> General”
choose “Network Connections”.
Select “Manual” from Action Provider drop-down list
Select the schema in the List and click the “Edit” button
Fill in the proxy server host and port number, (fill in the username and password if any)
Even after the above step, if the issue is not fixed, check your JDK and Mule compatibility(https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Anypoint-Platform-support-for-Oracle-Java-SE-8). After checking do the JDK path setting in Environment variable/Eclipse.ini.

Restart your machine and try to launch your Anypoint Studio.

If the issue is not fixed, then navigate to the Installation location of AnyPoint and then the configuration folder.

Open config.ini and crosscheck whether “eclipse.application” is empty or not.

If it is empty ,then assign “org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench” as value.

The above steps will fix the null issues while launching the AnypointStudio.

you can also refer below link: https://skolaparthi.com/mulesofterror/